# Logo Image float on a Image Slider Wordpress Theme CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**DISCLAIMER** : I did not code the theme. This was made by another developer who left the project and I am making adjustments based on the new requirements. I don't have experience in Wordpress Theming but I can understand codes.

I am making a design in a website and I want to make my logo to be like floating above the  Slider layer. I am working on a wordpress theme:

[image]

As you can see the Logo 'Red Dela Cruz' is on the top occupying a separate space or div. I want it inside the slider and floating on it like a layer, whenever the slide changes image, logo should still be there. Here is my code:

```
       <div class="slider">
            <img src="<?php echo $template_path; ?>images/redlogo_website.png" alt="" class="web-logo"/>
            <div id="one-by-one-slider" class="one-by-one-slider">
                <ul class="one-by-one-slider-large">

                    <?php
                          $args = array(
                              'post_type' => 'rdc_home', 
                              );
                           query_posts( $args );
                           // The Loop
                          if ( have_posts() ) : 
                          while (have_posts()) :
                          //the post for declaration
                          the_post();
                    ?>

                    <li>
                        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'thumbnail') ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
                        <div class="slider-content text-center">

                            <div class="slider-heading shp-12 slides" data-animation="bounceInDown" data-duration=4 data-delay=1>
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="slider-heading shp-13 slides" data-animation="bounceInDown" data-duration=6 data-delay=2>
                                <div class=" container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <div class="slider-heading shp-14 slides" data-animation="bounceInUp" data-duration=8 data-delay=4>
                                <div class=" container">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <a href="#contact" class="btn lm-gallery btn-remore">For Bookings</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    wp_reset_query();
                    ?>

                </ul>
                <div class="one-by-one-slider-nav">
                    <ul class="one-by-one-slider-thumbs">
                        <li class="one-by-one-slider-element"></li>
                        <?php
                              $args = array(
                                  'post_type' => 'rdc_home', 
                                  );
                               query_posts( $args );
                               // The Loop
                              if ( have_posts() ) : 
                              while (have_posts()) :
                              //the post for declaration
                              the_post();
                        ?>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                        <?php 
                               endwhile;
                               endif;
                               wp_reset_query();
                        ?>

                    </ul>
                </div><!-- one-by-one-slider-nav -->  

            </div><!-- one-by-one-slider -->
        </div><!-- slider -->
```

The logo is on the 2nd line and I haven't done any css on class

```
web-logo
```

Comment: can You run the code in fiddle

Comment: @ivinraj how? This is a wordpress theme.

Comment: ya ok wait i will do it sir

Comment: @ivinraj wow. thanks! This was a project left by another developer so I have no idea what to edit. My first time working on a wordpress theme.

Comment: wait sir i will try ok

Comment: @ivinraj sure, take your time. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
.web-logo {
    position:absolute;
}
```

If the logo goes "behind" the slider, you should add a z-index, and make it higher, untill the image is showing:

```
.web-logo {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Comment: Hi. it works in the positioning but problem is it is fading away. When the slider image is changing that is the only time I see the logo but it will fade away after the next image in the slider is loaded.

Comment: Try moving the <img /> outside the .slider-div

Comment: Working now :) As you suggested, I made the z index to 100 :D

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.web-logo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
   z-index:2;
}
```